# Find all intersections between 3 PHP arrays

Tags: php, data-structures, set, asymptotic-complexity

I am at a loss on how to find all "pairs" and "triplets" within 3 PHP arrays. My arrays look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sanitized] => lisa
            [original] => Lisa
            [weight] => 100
            [color] => blank
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sanitized] => jack
            [original] => Jack
            [weight] => 93
            [color] => blank
        )
    ...
```

There are 3 of these arrays; they are always sorted by the integer key, and they always contain 10 indices (0-9). What I am trying to do is:

- Find instances of identical names (by comparing the "sanitized" field) in either 2 of the arrays or all 3 arrays, and change their "color" to be the same (i.e. I don't want to find just the intersection between all 3 arrays - that can be done with array_intersect)
- Build a 4th array that joins all entries and combines identical names (by comparing the "sanitized" field) by summing their weights (colors don't matter)
- Since these tasks are similar, I'd like to do them at the same time, and minimize complexity

This is hard to explain, so I've represented it visually.

Colors:

[Colors http://www.tsiomenko.com/1.png](http://www.tsiomenko.com/1.png)

Weights:

[Weights http://www.tsiomenko.com/2.png](http://www.tsiomenko.com/2.png)

I have some working code, but it is really long, ugly, and has something like N^3 complexity - I use nested for-loops to traverse all the arrays multiple times until I have what I need. Even though I am working with really small arrays, I'd like to know how to do this efficiently, because I am curious how others would approach this problem. Pseudocode on how to approach this problem, instead of PHP, is welcome.

Comment: how do you determine the master color for an entry, e.g. how do you know which color to set when Lisa has "green" in array 1 and "yellow" in array 2. Which color would be chosen? Also, in the example the color is "blank". Where do you get the colors to assign from?

Comment: @Gordon I don't think it matters (it is really just `f(name)`) - in the output there are same-color highlights for the same person (who appear 2/3 times in the 3 inputs).

Comment: @Gordon - the color picked doesn't matter, as long as each group of identical names has their own color. Right now I am just pulling a random color from a premade array, and then making sure that color doesn't get picked again. Also should mention that each array is a set (i.e. all names within a single array are unique).

Comment: Your title says you want to find all intersections but your requirement then is to join all arrays? Can you clarify whether you want to join all values or just the intersecting ones?

Comment: @Gordon - sorry if the incorrectly-used set terminology is confusing. I am trying to 1) mark all groups of identical values with a separate color and 2) create a 4th set that joins all values and sums the weight of identical values. It's somewhat of a two-part problem. It's hard to explain, I tried to draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following loop should give the output you need:

```
// loop once to build the combined array and set the colors
foreach ($names as &$name) {
    if (!isset($combined[$name['sanitized']])) {
        $combined[$name['sanitized']] = array(
            'original' => $name['original'],
            'weight'   => $name['weight'],
            'color'    => array_pop($colors),
            'count'    => 1,
        );
    } elseif ($combined[$name['sanitized']]['count'] < 3) {
        $combined[$name['sanitized']]['weight'] += $name['weight'];
        $combined[$name['sanitized']]['count']++;
    }

    $name['color'] = $combined[$name['sanitized']]['color'];
}


// loop again to blank any colors where name only appeared once
foreach ($names as &$name) {
    if ($combined[$name['sanitized']]['count'] === 1) {
        $combined[$name['sanitized']]['color'] = $name['color'] = 'blank';
    }
}
```

I've omitted the color generator, for which there are many SO questions out there. One thing that remains somewhat unclear here is what to do if more than 3 matches are found, so you will probably have to modify the above to suit your needs.

[Here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/4482601) and [here's the generated output](http://codepad.org/WTcA7ZBS).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - mind you there are 3 separate "name" arrays, but I figured it out. Thanks for the very thorough response!